# Angular JS facebook like and ng-click

Tags: angularjs, facebook-like, angularjs-ng-click, voting-system

please am looking for a way to bind facebook like to my angularjs app, i already implemented easy app angularjs module, and everything is preety working fine.. how do i bind my ng click to the facebook like in such a way that it can only increase once and increment ones at the artistcontroller

```
 <section ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
<div class="row">
<div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()" ng-disabled="loginStatus.status == 'connected'">Connect with Facebook</button>
         &nbsp; 
        <button class="btn btn-danger " ng-click="logout()" ng-disabled="!loginStatus || loginStatus.status != 'connected'">Logout</button>
         &nbsp;
        <!--<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="share()">FB.ui</button>-->

      </div>
      <div>

      </div>
</div>

</div>


    <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">

                                <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></div>
                                <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="FILTER">
                            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">
    <p class="contest-text"> Welcome, <span ng-show="me.name">{{ me.name }}!</span></p>
    <span ng-show="me.name"><p class="contest-text">Vote For Your Favourite Goodnight Kiss Picture Below</p></span>
    <p class="contest-text"><span ng-show="me.error">Please Login To Vote</span></p>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;" ng-if="loginStatus.status == 'connected'">
    <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="item in contestant | filter: search | orderBy:artistOrder:direction" style="margin-bottom:30px">
        <div class="row text-center">
        <p>
            <img ng-src="uploads/{{item.ImageUrl}}" class="vote-img">

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <p class="contest-text">{{item.Name}}</p>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <p class="contest-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> {{item.Votes}} Votes </span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="row text-center">
<p class="contest-text voters"><a class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="upVote(item);"><b> VOTE</b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="share()">SHARE</button></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;" ng-if="!loginStatus || loginStatus.status != 'connected'">
            <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="item in contestant | filter: search | orderBy:artistOrder:direction" style="margin-bottom:30px">
        <div class="row text-center">
        <p>
            <img ng-src="uploads/{{item.ImageUrl}}" class="vote-img">

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <p class="contest-text">{{item.Name}}</p>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <p class="contest-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"> {{item.Votes}} Votes </span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!--    <div class="row text-center">
<p class="contest-text voters"><b> Please Login To VOTE</b></p>
        </div>-->
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

app.js controller code

```
var myApp = angular.module('votingApp', ['ezfb','ngRoute','artistController'])

.config(function (ezfbProvider) {
  /**
   * Basic setup
   *
   * https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb#configuration
   */
  ezfbProvider.setInitParams({
    appId: 'xxxxxx'
  });  
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ezfb, $window, $location, $q) {

  updateMe();

  updateLoginStatus()
  .then(updateApiCall);

  /**
   * Subscribe to 'auth.statusChange' event to response to login/logout
   */
  ezfb.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (statusRes) {
    $scope.loginStatus = statusRes;

    updateMe();
    updateApiCall();
  });

  $scope.login = function () {
    /**
     * Calling FB.login with required permissions specified
     * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.0
     */
    ezfb.login(null, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});

    /**
     * In the case you need to use the callback
     *
     * ezfb.login(function (res) {
     *   // Executes 1
     * }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'})
     * .then(function (res) {
     *   // Executes 2
     * })
     *
     * Note that the `res` result is shared.
     * Changing the `res` in 1 will also change the one in 2
     */
  };

  $scope.logout = function () {
    /**
     * Calling FB.logout
     * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout
     */
    ezfb.logout();

    /**
     * In the case you need to use the callback
     *
     * ezfb.logout(function (res) {
     *   // Executes 1
     * })
     * .then(function (res) {
     *   // Executes 2
     * })
     */
  };

  $scope.share = function () {
    var no = 1,
        callback = function (res) {
          console.log('FB.ui callback execution', no++);
          console.log('response:', res);
        };

    ezfb.ui(
      {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'angular-easyfb API demo',
        picture: 'http://plnkr.co/img/plunker.png',
        link: 'http://plnkr.co/edit/qclqht?p=preview',
        description: 'angular-easyfb is an AngularJS module wrapping Facebook SDK.' + 
                     ' Facebook integration in AngularJS made easy!' + 
                     ' Please try it and feel free to give feedbacks.'
      },
      callback
    )
    .then(callback);
  };

  /**
   * For generating better looking JSON results
   */
  var autoToJSON = ['loginStatus', 'apiRes']; 
  angular.forEach(autoToJSON, function (varName) {
    $scope.$watch(varName, function (val) {
      $scope[varName + 'JSON'] = JSON.stringify(val, null, 2);
    }, true);
  });

  /**
   * Update api('/me') result
   */
  function updateMe () {
    ezfb.getLoginStatus()
    .then(function (res) {
      // res: FB.getLoginStatus response
      // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus
      return ezfb.api('/me');
    })
    .then(function (me) {
      // me: FB.api('/me') response
      // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api
      $scope.me = me;
    });
  }

  /**
   * Update loginStatus result
   */
  function updateLoginStatus () {
    return ezfb.getLoginStatus()
      .then(function (res) {
        // res: FB.getLoginStatus response
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus
        $scope.loginStatus = res;
      });
  }

  /**
   * Update demostration api calls result
   */
  function updateApiCall () {
    return $q.all([
        ezfb.api('/me'),
        ezfb.api('/me/likes')
      ])
      .then(function (resList) {
        // Runs after both api calls are done
        // resList[0]: FB.api('/me') response
        // resList[1]: FB.api('/me/likes') response
        $scope.apiRes = resList;
      });

  }
});
```

controller.js

```
var artistController = angular.module("artistController", []);


//artistController.directive("otcdynamic", function($compile){


   // return{
        //  restrict: 'A',
    //    link: function(scope, element){
          //  var template = "<div class='selector'> <a class='btn btn-lg btn-warning' ng-click='upVote(item)'><b> VOTE</b></a></div>";
          //  var linkFn = $compile(template);
           // var content = linkFn(scope);
          //  element.append(content);
       // }
   // }
//});

//artistController.factory('facebook', [function() {
   // return FB;
//}]);



artistController.controller("LoginCtrl",['$scope',function($scope)
{

 $scope.notAuthorized = true;



 }]);

artistController.controller("ListController", ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http){

    $http.get('ajax/getContestant.php').success(function(data){


         $scope.contestant = data;
            // $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
    });
    $scope.upVote = function(item){

    item.Votes++;
    updateVote(item.ID,item.Votes);
  };

    function updateVote(id,votes){
    $http.post('ajax/updateVote.php?id='+id+'&votes='+votes);
  }

}]);
artistController.controller("DetailsController", ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams',function($scope, $http,$routeParams){

    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){


         $scope.artists  = data;
        $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemID;

        if ($routeParams.itemID > 0) {

            $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemID) -1;
        }
        else{

            $scope.prevItem = $scope.artists.length -1;
        }

if ($routeParams.itemID < $scope.artists.length -1) {

            $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemID) +1;
        }
        else{

            $scope.nextItem = 0;
        }
    });

}]);
```